# How to call Async Task with new Values?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-asynctask

public class BackgroundTasker extends AsyncTask {

```
    int progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        result.startAnimation(fadeIn);
        result.setTextSize(32);
        progressupdator(20);
        result.setText("Starting...");
    }


    @Override
    protected Long[] doInBackground(String... address) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            publishProgress(new Long[] { 
           MainActivity.this.getvalue(address[0]) });
        }
    }


    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values){
        if(values[0]==Long.valueOf(333)) {
            setProgress(100);
            result.setText("N/A");
            builder.setContentText("N/A");
            notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());
        }
        else{
            setProgress(100);
            result.setText(String.valueOf(values[0])+"ms");
            builder.setContentText(String.valueOf(values[0])+"ms");
            notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(int d) {
    }
```

@Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

```
                DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        BackgroundTasker r = new BackgroundTasker();
                        r.execute(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
                        Log.d("Fireabse", "Value is: " + value);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                        // Failed to read value
                        Log.w("Firebase", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                    }
                });
}
        });
```

I want that whenever the button connected to `onClick` is pressed, The `r.execute` take new values from Firebase Realtime Database and perform AsyncTask with the new values.

How do i do that?

Comment: What happens now and why?

Comment: @blackapps so right now, the old task that are running in doInBackground of the r thread dont stop, the new values are not sent to it. And the old task keeps on doing stuff un bothered

Comment: Yes you create a new asynctask indeed. And if there was already one running that will continue. Keep a refererence to the old task and apply r.cancel(). (Well i think that was the way to kill the old one. Please try).

Comment: @blackapps tried that too, what happens is, if i keep it before r.execute() , it destroys every new thread and wont execute.

Comment: Show us how you are using the AsyncTask.

Comment: @AlexMamo adding code

Comment: `tried that too, what happens is, if i keep it before r.execute() , it destroys every new thread and wont execute. `. Then show your adapted code. We dont know what you are doing else.